# Is it possible to write functions that do arithmetic in Bash?

Tags: bash

Like if I want to make a function that subtracts 2 numbers can I just just do `subtract() { $1 - $2}` and call it by doing `subtract $val1 $val2`? I'm completely new to Bash and I'm not so sure how it works yet and couldn't find anything on this online.

Comment: I absolutely don't believe the statement "couldn't find anything on this online"

Answer (score 1):

Bash has builtin arithmetic expansion `$(( expression ))`

So you only do

```
subtract() {
    echo $(( $1 - $2 ))
}
A=8
B=5
result=$(subtract $A $B)
echo $result
```

Output:

```
3
```